# firewall blocking local network access even though firewall shows inactive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, vps

So I have 2 VPS, both Ubuntu.

it's as follows:

1. Has OpenVPN on it, and I use that VPN
2. Has a website that I would like to be able to connect to, but it's not connecting when my VPN is running from server #1

As a said, firewall is inactive, when I run sudo ufw status, it says "Status: inactive"

is there any possible reason for that to happen?